# customise or use another column for facet_wrap labels

Tags: axis-labels, facet-wrap

[image: Image of the plot is here]

[image: Image of the data is here]

I have been able to deploy abbreviated months in facet_wrap labels, but I want to use J,F,M,A,M,J,J,A,S,O,N,D kind of labels in place. My code is as follows.

```
   ggplot(sr3, aes(x=Month2, fill = Year)) +  geom_bar() + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
   facet_wrap(~Province) +
   labs(title ="US Drone Strikes in Afghanistan from Jan 2015- Mar 2018", 
   x = "Monthly distribution across Provinces", y = "No. of Strikes")
```

Comment: The problem is that how to order the letters when J means January, June and July or say M means March, May.....also can I reverse the order of year stacked. As I want earliest year to show at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work with factor:

```
   ggplot(transform(sr3, Month2=factor(Month2, levels=c("J","F","M",......))),aes(x=Month2, fill = Year)) +  geom_bar() + 
   theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
   facet_wrap(~Province) +
   labs(title ="US Drone Strikes in Afghanistan from Jan 2015- Mar 2018", 
   x = "Monthly distribution across Provinces", y = "No. of Strikes")
```

Comment: My fear came true. It gave an error for March and May as follows.
`Error in `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : 
  factor level [5] is duplicated`

Comment: I have tried to create another column with the code as follows:
`sr3$Month3 <- factor(substr(sr3$Month, 1,1), 
                     levels = c("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"))`
but the problem is again that of duplicate level errors. How to handle this.

Comment: May be keep levels as they are and change the labels with `scale_x_discrete=(labels=c("J","F","M","N","M"......)`? Would be a workaround but may solve it.

Comment: Thanks the final code that worked for me is

`ggplot(sr3, aes(x=Month, fill = Year)) +  geom_bar() + 
scale_x_discrete(labels = 
c("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D")) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
facet_wrap(~Province) +
labs(title ="US Drone Strikes in Afghanistan from Jan 2015- Mar 2018", 
   x = "Monthly distribution across Provinces", y = "No. of Strikes")`
But, the last problem is how to change the order of year stacked.

Comment: Just last thing how to modify the stack of year into reverse order. That would finish my task.

Comment: I think you can use the method at levels with years. That should change the order.

Comment: Yes thanks I used `geom_bar(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE, vjust = .5))` and it helped me.